# C# login form doesn`t work

Tags: c#, forms, authentication

I`ve made a login form with access db, which I only need the password from.
The connection to db is successful, but when I press the button, the messagebox shows me "incorrect password", even if I insert a correct one from my db.
here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace TAC_receptie
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:login1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText="select * from user1 where Password =' " +txtPassword.Text+ " '";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
           date_personale Form = new date_personale();
           Form.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("duplicat!!!");
            }

            if (count < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("parola incorecta!!!");
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {         
           connection.Open();

           connection.Close();
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Error"+ ex);
        }
    }

    private void txtPassword_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            btnLogin.PerformClick();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove unnecessary space from

```
Password =' " +txtPassword.Text+ " '"
```

to

```
Password ='" +txtPassword.Text.Trim()+ "'"
```